# How to use substitutionGroup in xml schema for elements inside complexType?

Tags: xml, xsd

How to make this work?
for example:

```
<xs:element name="name" 
            type="xs:string" 
            substitutionGroup="firstname"/>
```

for this code bellow...

```
<xs:complexType name="basic">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "work"? Do you want a sequence of elements in the `firstname` substitution group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitution groups can only be headed by top-level elements; the 'firstname' element you declare within complex type 'basic' is local to that complex type, and so cannot be named by your 'name' element as the head of its substitution group.

To understand why, ask yourself:  if there were three other local elements named 'firstname' in the schema, two of them strings and one of them a boolean, then how would the XSD validator decide which one is meant by the reference in the declaration of 'name'?